# Flattening dynamic JSON content to SQL Server in ADF

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-factory, flatten

I am trying to flatten the dynamic JSON and put the result into a SQL Server table, but I have been unable to do so.
I have tried the below ways so far.

- Copy Activity. The json data from a db table column is not recognized as Json. Left out.
- Data flow (Flatten). The json doesn't contain an array. Left out.
- Data Flow (Parser). The json data has a flexible structure and it wouldn't fit either.

The dynamic survey form creates results in JSON shown below.

Form a:

```
{
  "q637481270215": { //form unique id
    "q16124907150": "Jonny Smith",  //name question unique id
    "q16124907408": "Yes",
    "q16124907765": "08/06/2022",   // form unique id for the form created data time
    "q16124908929": {
      "q16124909751": "7",
      "q16124910746": "7",
      "q16124910747": "I'd love to find an answer."
    }
  }
}
Form n:
{
  "q637481270216": {
    "q161249071512": "Susan Smith",
    "q161249074092": "No",
    "q161249077662": "18/06/2022",
    "q161249089302": {
      "q161249097522": "7",
      "q161249107472": "7",
      "q161249107482": "I'd love to find an answer."
    }
    ,
    "q161249089303": {
      "q161249097523": "Yes",
      "q161249107573": "7",
      "q161249107583": "9"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to flatten/parse the results into a SQL Server table like this:

```
FormId          QuestionPropertyId      Answer
---------------------------------------------------------
q637481270215   q16124907150            Jonny Smith
q637481270215   q16124907408            Yes
q637481270215   q16124907765            08/06/2022
q637481270215   q16124908929            {{object}} or disregard
q637481270215   q16124909751            7
q637481270215   q16124910746            7
q637481270215   q16124910747            I'd love to find an answer.

q637481270216   q161249071512           Susan Smith
q637481270216   q161249074092           No
q637481270216   q161249077662           18/06/2022
q637481270216   q161249089302           {{object}} or disregard
q637481270216   q161249097522           7
q637481270216   q161249107472           7
q637481270215   q161249107482           I'd love to find an answer.
......
q637481270216   q161249089303           {{object}} or disregard
q637481270216   q161249097523           No
.........
```

Is there any way to transform the Json content to the desired output format to a SQL Server table using Azure ADF?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Have you at least got the dynamic parsing happening in T-SQL code yet? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72496494/edit) your question to show us what you have tried.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, It could be a right approach. I'd better use TSQL code. I am afraid ADF doesn't parse dynamic complex JSON data.

Comment: ADF can invoke T-SQL code by way of Stored Procedure activities - even if that means executing your own code in your own stored procedures, or with a block of T-SQL passed in a call to `sp_executesql` - so it can still be done in an ADF workflow.

Comment: I found an answer from here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168303/can-sql-server-2016-extract-node-names-from-json

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON structure is not supported to flatten using the Azure data factory. You can check this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json) for supported JSON patterns in the azure data factory.

Alternatively, you can use the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to parse it in your SQL.